# How to format the data in sql query using postgres

Tags: sql, json, postgresql

I have table name : locations

`colums => location, ltn,lgn`

data in table:

```
Banguluru, 22,24,
Banguluru, 22,25
Banguluru, 22,26
Hyderabad, 22,27
```

I want output like this:

```
{ 
    location: 'Hyderabad',
        positions :  [
            position : {
                lat: 22,
                lng: 27                 
        }]
    },
{
        location: 'Banguluru',
        positions :  [
            position : {
               lat: 22,
                lng: 24                 
        },  position : {
               lat: 22,
                lng: 25
        },  position : {
               lat: 22,
                lng: 26
       }]}
```

Answer (score 0):

sample:

```
t=# create table s170 (location text, ltn int,lgn int);
CREATE TABLE
t=# insert into s170 values ('Banguluru',24,25),('Banguluru',24,26),('Hyderabad',22,27);
INSERT 0 3
```

query:

```
t=# with b as (
  with a as (
    select location, (select to_json(position) from (select ltn,lgn) as position) as position
    from s170
  )
  select location,json_agg(position) as position
  from a
  group by location
)
select json_agg(b)
from b;
                                     json_agg
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 [{"location":"Hyderabad","position":[{"ltn":22,"lgn":27}]},                     +
  {"location":"Banguluru","position":[{"ltn":24,"lgn":25}, {"ltn":24,"lgn":26}]}]
(1 row)
```

or in pretty:

```
[
  {
    "location": "Hyderabad",
    "position": [
      {
        "ltn": 22,
        "lgn": 27
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "location": "Banguluru",
    "position": [
      {
        "ltn": 24,
        "lgn": 25
      },
      {
        "ltn": 24,
        "lgn": 26
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

I believe one CTE wrap could be easily skipped, but let it be here for code clarity

**update**
for 9.2 this should do:

```
t=# with b as (
  with a as (
    select location, (select row_to_json(position,true) from (select ltn,lgn) as position) as position
    from s170
  )
  select location,string_agg(position::text,',') as position
  from a
  group by location
)
select string_agg(concat('{"location":"',location,'","position":[',position,']}'), ',')
from b;
string_agg
{"location":"Hyderabad","position":[{"ltn":22,
 "lgn":27}]},{"location":"Banguluru","position":[{"ltn":24,
 "lgn":25},{"ltn":24,
 "lgn":26}]}
(1 row)
```

Comment: actually to_json  json_agg not working in my postgres 9.2

Comment: yes - it works from 9.3 you should have specified your version in original post